# 3.5 mm adaptor shortages/poor connection?

Tags: audio, live

Every single 3.5 mm adaptor I have purchased or worked with throughout my career and life has had a short in it. Some of the frequencies will come through, but not all. Sometimes it's the highs and mids, but not the lows. Left channel, but not right. And I always have to turn it slightly to get a signal, pull it out a little bit for it to work or it just doesnt work at all! Honestly. At this point I don't know why they even sell this bs. Should I even bother wasting my time with adapters to 3.5 mm Jack's? Is there a solution to the horrible signals?

Answer (score 4):

Listen mate, if you are having a problem with every single 3.5mm adapter you have purchased, it's probably the socket.

Answer (score 1):

I used to design and build audio circuits. Loads of them. I probably bought over 500 3.5mm jack plugs, sockets and adaptors. All worked perfectly.

Occasionally I messed up a connection, and so needed to sort out a short. In those cases one or other channel was missing. In no instance were highs/mids/lows affected - a short will just not do this. To affect a particular frequency range you need a filter (eg a hi-pass or low pass) and these require a component which provides frequency dependent response (such as a capacitor or inductor)

A short is not frequency dependent (in any of the circuits you are going to be talking about - there are some exceptions up in the high GHz scale, but that's a very different beast)

So as @Mark said, you probably have a problem with your **other** hardware, such as your socket. If it's on multiple hardware, maybe you are being too rough with them and damaging the contacts.

Comment: Though I'm in complete agreement with yourself & Mark on this... there is probably a very good reason pro rigs don't use mini-jacks... XLRs you could probably smack with a reasonably weighty hammer several times, with no adverse effects.